# Laravel many to many relationship making a list with pivot table for order

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have made a list of all items using many to many relationship.
With a pivot I make sure that there is an order.
Now I am trying to remove 1 item from the list.
And the order numbers must also move, this does not work.

From the view I provide the `$id` of the item and the order number.

```
public function removefromlist($id, $nummer)
{
    $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
    $user->manytomany()->detach($id);
    $nummerlist = $user->manytomany()->count();
    for($i = $nummer + 1;$i <= $nummerlist;$i++){
        $testt = $user->manytomany()->where('nummer', $i);
        $user->manytomany()->updateExistingPivot($testt->first()->item_id , ['nummer' => $i -1]);
    }

    return view('welcome')->with('itemslist', $user->manytomany);
}
```

How can I ensure that when I delete an item, the other move up?

Comment: show the table data and desired output.

Comment: What is the relationship defined on User model for the item - is it really named `manytomany`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```php
public function removefromlist($id, $nummer)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    $user->manytomany()->detach($id);

    $user->manytoMany()
        ->where('nummer', '>', $nummer)
        ->get()
        ->each(function($item) use($user) {
            $user->manytomany()
                ->updateExistingPivot(
                    $item->id, 
                    ['nummer' => $item->pivot->nummer - 1]
                );
        });


    return view('welcome')->with('itemslist', $user->manytomany);

}
```